# How can I upload a not-utf-8 encoded file using Python's requests module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, encoding, python-requests

I want to upload an iso-8859-1 encoded csv file to an API endpoint which expects iso-8859-1 files.

When I use this code, I get an UTF-8 encoded file at the backend:

```
url = 'http://example.com/strange_api'
content =  open("iso-8859-1-file.csv", 'r', encoding="iso-8859-1")
files = {'file': content}
response = requests.request("POST", url, files=files)
```

When I post the same file from the browser to the same endpoint, the backend gets an iso-8859-1 encoded file, so I assume that there is something wrong with my Python code snippet.

```
<form method="post" action="http://example.com/strange_api" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="file" type="file" size="50" >
  <button>Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you try by setting `headers` parameter as well: `headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-1', 'Accept-Charset': 'iso-8859-1'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This decodes your file from 8859-1 to internal Unicode representation:

> ```
> content =  open("iso-8859-1-file.csv", 'r', encoding="iso-8859-1")
> ```

This encodes your data as UTF-8 by default, because what you are sending is not bytes:

> ```
> response = requests.request("POST", url, files=files)
> ```

Read the file as bytes, using `open(..., "rb")`; it would be sent with original encoding; [`requests` documentation suggests that](https://3.python-requests.org/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file).